# Swift subclass' init must set all properties before calling super but property requires super's init to complete first

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write two Swift classes, one is a subclass of the other and needs to take one of the superclass' properties and use that to configure its self.

```
class BaseClass {
    let someValue: Double
    let size: CGSize

    init (size: CGSize) {
        self.size = size
        self.someValue = size.width / 2.0 //Doesn't really matter how this is calculated
    }
}

class Subclass: BaseClass {
    let someNewValue: Double

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        self.someNewValue = self.someValue * 2
    }
}
```

The problem is that the subclass requires that its call to `super.init` is after it sets initial values for all of its properties. However the `self.someNewValue = self.someValue * 2` call which does this, relies on the super's init having been called first to set `self.someValue`. I guess I could get around this by turning `let someValue: Double` to `var someValue: Double` on the BaseClass, and then set its value in the subclass's init as well as the base class's init, but that just seems bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two solutions here:

Make `someNewValue` implicitly unwrapped optional

```
class Subclass: BaseClass {
    let someNewValue: Double!

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        self.someNewValue = self.someValue * 2
    }
}
```

or give `someNewValue` some default value before calculating its final value

```
class Subclass: BaseClass {
    let someNewValue: Double = 0.0

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        self.someNewValue = self.someValue * 2
    }
}
```

Both approches shouldn't cause any problems

Comment: I didn't realize you could set a default value and then change it in init. I thought the whole point of creating a let variable is that once set it can't be changed. Guess I'll use this method though, I'm trying to avoid the optional types in Swift for now because I find it confusing, with a couple different types of optionals.

Comment: Yeah, constant let instance variables can be changed within init. Unwrapped optionals are sometimes required in this case. Your example has Double type property, which is very simple. Sometimes however you have complex types and it is hard or expensive to set any default value.

Comment: I just tried adding a ```let someArray = [1, 2, 3]```, then in init calling ```self.someArray.append(4)``` and it worked. So all immutable objects are mutable inside init. That seems like a mess.

Comment: What potential pitfalls do you see? You can only modify let constants that are declared by the type (forbidden for subclass properties).

Comment: I can just imagine working on legacy code in a couple years where you have a massive class and see its got an array or dict defined with let and default value, then you think that's the value it will have throughout the class. But in reality they completely changed its values in init, but due to code size &| organization you don't have the init 2 lines away to see that it changes.

Comment: These solutions work, it just seems like poor programming practice to initialize a variable just to reassign it. Or to give a variable an optional type if we don't want it to be optional at all.

Comment: The second solution doesn't seem to work in Swift 2 (you get the error "Immutable value may only be initialized once")